# Bash script to automatically create symlinks from file with file list

Tags: symlink, busybox

I have file `list.txt` with file list.

```
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
file_4.txt
.....
.....
.....
file_50.txt
```

I need create symlink for all files.

Example

```
file_1.txt > newfile_1.txt
file_2.txt > newfile_2.txt
file_3.txt > newfile_3.txt
file_4.txt > newfile_4.txt
.....
.....
.....
file_50.txt > newfile_50.txt
```

I tested this

```
cat list.txt | egrep -v '^#|^[[:space:]]*$' | xargs ln -sf
```

but not works.

Comment: Is all you need a constant file prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a constant filename prefix and the list contains only basenames without directories, the following shell loop should work:

```
while read f; do
    ln -sf "$f" "new$f"
done < list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you have other idea. I have enigma machine (this is only basic linux) and `while` not work

Comment: Then why is this tagged [tag:bash]?

Comment: Enigma use script in bash but I don´t have command `while` in this system. Enigma is basic linux system for satellite receiver (e.g VU+ Solo2)

Comment: What does "enigma machine" stand for, other than [the obvious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine)?

Comment: `while` is a Bash builtin; if you have Bash, you have `while`.

Comment: @skyndas JUST TESTED. (on my VU+ Duo) - the shell **has** the `while`. It uses `busybox` - try it yourself. ;)

Comment: **For example:** [link](http://www.reichelt.de/Receiver-DVB-S2-HDTV-/VUSOLOSE-S2-SW/3/index.html?ACTION=3&GROUPID=4090&ARTICLE=147196&OFFSET=16&SID=11VSKlHKwQATMAAAxzp8M5bc636b6eb4a37ed2baca731e1090ff4&LANGUAGE=EN)

Comment: @skyndas: Uh, `while` is a Bash builtin command. If you are using Bash, then `while` *should* exist. Perhaps you are using some sort of tiny shell for embedded devices like [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/)?

Comment: @jm666: Thanks. OK. So I do some mistake :-)

Comment: @skyndas: that said, my own version of busybox works just fine with the commands in my answer...